# How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, textview, compound-drawables

Ran the new Lint tool against my code.  It came up with a lot of good suggestions, but this one I cannot understand.

> This tag and its children can be replaced by one  and a compound drawable
>
> Issue: Checks whether the current node can be replaced by a TextView using compound drawables.
>
> A LinearLayout which contains an ImageView and a TextView can be more efficiently handled as a compound drawable

And here is my layout

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_centerInParent="true">

<ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/upImage"
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:src="@drawable/up_count_big">
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/LikeCount"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
</TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone provide a concrete example of how to make a compound drawable in this case?

Comment: fwiw that's one of the checks I normally disable, because of the false positives. Not all `TextView` / `ImageView` combos can be replaced in this way.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier You can use custom view if you want to define a size of image. This will make your view lighter. See my answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/31916731/2308720

Comment: @Alex I agree in many cases, however in my experience I have often it not worth the trouble of creating a custom view to get around what I consider to be a buggy Lint check.

Answer (score 286, accepted):

`TextView` comes with 4 compound drawables, one for each of left, top, right and bottom.

In your case, you do not need the `LinearLayout` and `ImageView` at all. Just add `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/up_count_big"` to your `TextView`.

See [TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) for more info.

Comment: not necessarily, as your link shows an example with a dynamic image. In that case it may still be easier or preferable to use an `ImageView`. The warning says 'can be replaced by', not 'should be replaced by'

Comment: but how can I make some space between Image and Text

Comment: @Hitesh Dhamshaniya, using DrawablePadding property in XML or code.

Comment: and you can also link TextView drawables to xml states, explained here: http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/textview-drawables-xml-state-list-resource/

Comment: In my case, I moved to a LinearLayout with an inner ImageView/TextView because the android:drawableLeft didn't offer enough control -- so, what you're basically telling me is that this warning/suggestion is a lie.

Comment: It's not a lie, for some cases a single TextView could indeed be efficient. But in general - yes, ImageView with TextView provides much richer control.

Comment: And how do you apply tinting to the compound drawables? I need that option?

Comment: @Puni, do you use SVG images? If yes, you should add a support.

Answer (score 23):

if for some reason you need to add via code, you can use this:

```
mTextView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
```

where left, top, right bottom are Drawables

Comment: Require API 17 above

Comment: I don't think so, [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html) states since API 1

Comment: See this link [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))

Comment: yeah note the **Relative** in the method name ;) I'm not referring to this one in the answer

Answer (score 3):

To add to this - it seems important to define the width & height of the drawable as per this post:

- [Drawable shape not showing when used in combination with android:drawableBottom attribute.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6865765/383414)

(his code works)

Answer (score 1):

You can use general compound drawable implementation, but if you need to define a size of drawable use this library:

https://github.com/a-tolstykh/textview-rich-drawable

Here is a small example of usage:

```
<com.tolstykh.textviewrichdrawable.TextViewRichDrawable
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text"
        app:compoundDrawableHeight="24dp"
        app:compoundDrawableWidth="24dp" />
```