# How to set height and width of compound drawable textview in xml?

Tags: android, xml, compound-drawables

I can't see any tag to set width

Here I set textview height, if I set width it will not work properly.

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/nome"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
   android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:height="50dp" />
```

How can I set this in xml? Is it possible?

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is not working? What errors are you getting? ect

Comment: I want set the image size to 50dp/50dp

Comment: you have two viable answers.  hence -1

Comment: You can achieve this by creating the right size images for each dimension. For mdpi you should use 50px by 50px, for hdpi you should use 75px by 75px, or xhdpi you should use 100px by 100px. The TextView will use the intrinsic size of these images.

Comment: This question should not be closed , the question is VERY clear and one of the top search results on the topic. Stack really needs some better admins

Comment: @ChuckKelly It is possible to do it with custom view. It is additional code, but only once. See my comment - http://stackoverflow.com/a/31916731/2308720

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Home"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Something"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<ImageView 
    android:src="@drawable/icon" 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Home"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

This way I think you would have more control of your image. Hope that helps.

Comment: YES, i was doing like this, but eclipse said not to do this. thank you  I will forget eclipse warnings

Comment: That is weird. Yea no problem.

Comment: Well the whole point of compound drawables is to avoid using an entire layout like this.

Answer (score -2):

try setting to `android:width="50dip"` and see what you get. dip is device independent pixels.   You should be able to see in eclipse in design view.  You cannot just set to "300"

Comment: If i set width the text will not appear.. because it set the width of the textview

Comment: I see so you want it to wrap?

Comment: Actually what you need to do is just create an image button and place it to the left.

Comment: So just create another LinearLayout set to horizontal orientation and place the ImageView to the left.

Comment: Or actually I think you might be able to pass the ImageView as the drawable left. Note sure about that however.

Comment: I was using an imageview and a textview, and it works perfectly. But eclipse said to use the drawable in the textview.

Comment: I thought it will work better, maybe android team forgot to introduce the tags for the drawable

Comment: Here is a link about how to use it. http://izvornikod.com/Blog/tabid/82/EntryId/8/Creating-Android-button-with-image-and-text-using-relative-layout.aspx

Comment: Never mind eclipse its loco.  Just get rid of the drawableLeft.