# Action bar action button icon size

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Our app uses Action Bar Sherlock, and it has a theme like such:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.Default" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBar.Light.ActionButton</item>
    <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/MyApp.SherlockActionBar.Light.ActionButton</item>
</style>
<style name="MyApp.SherlockActionBar.Light.ActionButton" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionButton">
        <item name="android:maxHeight">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:maxWidth">20dp</item>
    </style>
```

Where `Theme.MyApp.Default` is the default theme for the app.

I need to set the icons for the action buttons (#2 on [this image](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)) to be a specific size.  When I set the `height/width/scaleX/scaleY/scaleType/padding` properties however, the icon on the button still maintain what looks like their pixel size. The text part of the action button does seems to adhere to the setting though. Could it just be a compound drawable on a textview?

How can I set the size of the icon on the action bar?

Answer (score 1):

Action bar icons for phones should be 32x32 dp.

Action bar icons are graphic buttons that represent the most important actions people can take within your app. Each one should employ a simple metaphor representing a single concept that most people can grasp at a glance.

you refer that link [here](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleaned your project and then run?
and you can specify action item height in main.xml(actionbar menu layout ) also though contrl space wont wrk its like normal height prperty.
whenever changing styles you have to clean and run the project

Comment: Rebuilding project didn't work.  Not sure what property you are refering to as "action item height"  I can't find references to it with Google.

Answer (score 0):

More and more evidence points to the fact that the menu on the action bar is a compound drawable. (Setting the property `android:drawablePadding` moves the icon from the text.) And seeing that [you can't scale the image in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9168212/8524) for a compound drawable, this doesn't seem possible at the moment.