# How to make drawable height depends of the textview's text height?

Tags: android

I need to add a drawable inside my textview and makes it take the same height as the text.

My xml :

```
...<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutId">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/greenarrowup"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/greenarrowup"
            /> ...
```

What I'm getting : 
[image: Actual result]

What I want : 
[image: desired result]

I've tried using imageView to get the desired result but didn't make it, can someone help me please ?
Thank you.

Comment: Interesting question. See [this question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168021/compounddrawable-size).

Answer (score 0):

You should set the horizontal orientation of the linear layout and use the imageview like this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayoutId">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingEnd="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            /> 

        <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/greenarrowup" />


        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add certain height on textview and set gravity to be vertically centered

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this is not what I need.