# Android: Adding text below an image

Tags: android, layout

I am trying to have an image be fitted, and have a layout below it with some black background and whit text. My problem is that the layout ends up leaving space between the image and the text itself, and I don't understand why:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/image" >

        <TextView
            style="@style/text_overlay"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

         <!-- Couple more elements -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I would want this second RelativeLayout of 15dp touch the bottom of the image, but unless I change the image height to something small, it leaves some space. This layout specifies how to display an image + some text below it, but I have a total of 4 images that use this layout to get loaded on the screen, in a 2x2 display. (Each image takes 25% of the screen).

Any idea how to make the RelativeLayout align exactly with the bottom of the image please?

Answer (score 0):

I do not fully understand your question though I think you might have a look at the launcher layout for my Newspaper Puzzles app...

- http://code.google.com/p/newspaper-puzzles/source/browse/np/res/layout/launcher_layout.xml

or perhaps from the Open Sudoku Game look at the number pad layout found here:

- http://code.google.com/p/newspaper-puzzles/source/browse/np/res/layout/s_im_numpad.xml

Use the ADT tools to get the right layout is probably best if possible but I know sometimes it is difficult to use to get specific results I still recommend using the xml tools included in the Android Development Tools.

- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adt.html#graphical-editor

Comment: Well I am trying to have an image, and right below it some text / images (some kind of layout) that takes it's width. The layout is leaving spacing / padding between the two.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend using a compound drawable if you're trying to put text directly below an ImageView.

See the following question for more details: [How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag)

Comment: I have 2 TextViews and 1 ImageView making up the bottom part of the image. I don't think I can make it work.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it's still appreciated. Thanks!