# Image + Text to be centre alligned in button

Tags: android, android-button

I have a Button with its width as `match_parent`. And I want a image/icon with a text in its center. I have tried`android:drawableStart` attribute but its of no help. I don't know what  I am missing. Is there any one who is also facing the same problem.

Note:[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3634191/how-to-center-icon-and-text-in-a-android-button-with-width-set-to-fill-parent) is not solving my problem. I am attaching my button portion of xml

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
    android:id="@+id/btn_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_list"
    android:text="@string/btn_schedule"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

After adding these attribute my text is coming on center but image/icon is still on left side of button. Can any body help!!!

Comment: why dont you try android:layout_gravity="center"

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check my answer to this question:
[Android Button with text and image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927896/android-button-with-text-and-image)

Its an ugly solution but it you want the image and text to be centered as a group in the button rather than text center and drawable padded from the side then its the only way I have found.

Comment: Using that will mend the default behavior, and I kindda do that as my last option available. I want to stick with android default behavior unless I am left with no other option then to create my own widget.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I hadn't found anywhere clear solution. BUT I got some information which also help me to provide following solutions (I have chosen the second one):

1. Create image which will contain your image and text

   ```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
   ```
2. It is not so clear and you have to add more complicated changes to your layout but it is easier to modify the text later

   ```
    <FrameLayout
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" /> 

        <TextView
            android:text="sample"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
    </FrameLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

100% working

```
<FrameLayout
style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@null"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
    android:text="Button Challenge" />
```

from [here](http://porcupineprogrammer.blogspot.co.il/2013/03/android-ui-struggles-making-button-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Basically play with the paddingLeft and PaddingRight of the button to get the text and image close together to the center.

Note: Might be an issue with rather long texts.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="search button"
            android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_action_search"
            android:paddingLeft="60dp"
            android:paddingRight="60dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried `android:drawableTop`

The image shown in the center of the button

Comment: `android:drawableTop` is for top not for start of text