# Wrapping a StateListDrawable

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have a view, on which I set a `StateListDrawable` (defines `state_pressed` and the default state) as a the `background` in XML. This works fine, all the states are displayed as expected.

I now want to programmatically draw something on top of the `StateListDrawable`, no matter in which state it is. For this, I created a Java class that extends `Drawable`, which holds the original background drawable; in `onDraw` it first draws the original drawable to the canvas and then its own additions. This also works, but the state of the original drawable doesn't change.

I can see that `setState` of my custom `Drawable` is called with a `stateSet` that contains `android.R.attr.state_pressed` among some other states. I delegate that call to the original drawable, but there `setState` always returns `false` and its state doesn't change. It only changes when I pass a `stateSet` containing **nothing but `android.R.attr.state_pressed`**.

It seems as if the `StateListDrawable` somehow can announce the stateSets it is interested in and the caller of `setState` respecting that, although I didn't find anything related in the docs or the Android source.

This is my `setState`:

```
@Override public boolean setState(int[] stateSet) {
    boolean changed = super.setState(stateSet);
    if (originalBackground != null) {
        // this call only returns true and changes the state if
        // the stateSet *only* contains the pressed state
        changed |= originalBackground.setState(stateSet);
    }
    return true;
}
```

My original background `Drawable`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@color/red"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/green"/>
</selector>
```

How can I make the original drawable change its state without filtering the `stateSet` for `state_pressed`?

Comment: Hannes, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927896/android-button-with-text-and-image/17542264#17542264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to pskink's example I tried calling `invalidateSelf` in `onStateChanged`, which did the trick.

Comment: btw if you extended Drawable, did you override isStateful() ?

Comment: yep, if I didn't, I think setState wouldn't be called at all.