# Android Eclipse how to add an image button with text

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag)

I currently just have just a button with text in it but now I want to add a background image to it. But I don't want the background image to cover the whole button. I would like it to look something like the buttons in this picture. (Look at the picture under the app screenshots, it's the first image.) Here is a link to the picture.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pxstudios.minecraftpro&feature=related_apps#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEwOSwiY29tLnB4c3R1ZGlvcy5taW5lY3JhZnRwcm8iXQ..

Answer (score 1):

You mean the list view with the text to the right of the buttons?  You use two views, a text view and an image view

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <ImageView ...>
    <TextView ...>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: OK. thanks but is their any other way. Because I have at lease 200 buttons and thats going to be a lot of text

Comment: Create a new View subclass that consists of this layout.  Then you can just declare it by name.  Although if you have 200-  you're probably going to throw it into a ListView?  In that case, you'll be inflating it in code in the GetView function of your adapter and not putting 200 of them in xml.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/[your_image]"
    android:text="Your_Text"
    android:textSize="48dp" //<==give a dimension to a text
    android:textStyle="bold"//<==is better your text is bold
     />
```

If u use Eclipse, use graphic editor to create how many buttons you wants, just copy and paste in your Xml file. And use Strings.xml to store your text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:drawableLeft attribute to set the icon to the left. Button is derived from TextView so it supports this attribute,