# Text align with SpannableString

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one TextView with text and an image in it. To let it work I set a SpannableString to that TextView as below. My image is shown correctly but the text will be bottom aligned with the image however the gravity of the TextView is center_vertical. I know I can solve this easily with a separate TextView and ImageView but, I want to solve it with 1 TextView as it is part of the text and the image can be everywhere in the text.

```
ss = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.MyString) + " $");
ss.setSpan(new ImageSpan(ctx, R.drawable.myIcon), ss.length() - 1, ss.length(), 0);
tv.setText(ss);
```

My TextView will look like

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a spannable textview its better if you would use a [CoupoundDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:drawableEnd) in android TextView. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag) link has answers on how to use it.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't meet my requirements. The image can be even in the middle of text. It depends in which language the text will be. We will foresee a placeholder in the text where the image should be.