# Issue with onclicklistener to LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In order to group a icon and a text, I have grouped them together in a linearlayout and implemented a listener for the linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imageButton0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:src="@drawable/start" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Start"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

I have implemented the listener, the following way:-

```
l0 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll0);
l0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            //Some Code
        }
    });
```

The issue I'm facing is that which I click on the icon, the listener doesn't seem to respond. The listener worked when I click the space in between the textview and the icon. I would like the whole part to be clickable, not at a particular point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the `ImageButton` is a clickable view and is capturing the click, preventing the LinearLayout from receiving the click event. Try to add `android:clickable="false"` to the XML defining the `ImageButton`.

However, a better answer is to use a compound drawable. See [How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8318765/687315). Basically you can add `android:drawableTop="@drawable/start"` to the XML defining the `TextView` and do away with the `LinearLayout` and `ImageButton` altogether. Then you just handle the click on the `TextView`.

Comment: android:clickable doesn't seem to be helping, but the compound drawable works good.