# This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable: picture and text

Tags: android

I have this codes

```
<ImageView
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="20dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:background="@drawable/tick"
                        android:contentDescription="img" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/txt1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:text="text1 "
                        android:textColor="#fff"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/sizeNormal" />
```

and i am having a warning `This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable`

How i can merge them to one textview?

i have tried but in the same time i have tick image dimension problem.

here you can see the image

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag)

Comment: I have hecked also. But itis not solution for me as we nned to resize the tickimg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *is* just a warning and the app should still compile and run. However, this doesn't mean that you just want to dismiss all warnings.

Now, there are different ways to do this. You could use `drawableLeft` in your xml. Something like

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/txt1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
      android:text="text1 "
      android:textColor="#fff"
      android:textSize="@dimen/sizeNormal"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tick />
```

You can also see [here in the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablePadding%28int%29) of different ways of adjusting it in your Java code.

To set the `padding` between the image and the text, try using

```
yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(somePadding);
```

where `somePadding` is an `int` for the value of the `padding` you want.

Comment: need to decide image layout dimensions also

Comment: Looks like you need to scale your image down

Comment: i changed the size of img now how iwill take text little bit to right

Comment: Look at those methods I linked to. They all you to add padding, I believe. On my phone but maybe I can look in a bit if you don't get it

Comment: I need to put a space between img and text

Comment: i will add this yourTextView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(somePadding);   tomy java code?

Comment: Yes. Obviously `yourTextView` will be what you name it in your code but I'm hoping you understand that

Comment: i found teh reply  android:drawablePadding="25"

Comment: That would work also to do it in xml. All of those options are detailed in the docs I linked to

Answer (score 1):

USe the text **Compound Drawables.**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/g_device_access_storage"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/g_navigation_refresh"
    android:paddingRight="55dp"
    android:text="hello" />
```