# This tag and it's children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compund drawable

Tags: android

When I move mouse over `LinearLayout` I get a warning, how can I get rid of it?

> This tag and its children can be replaced by one TextView/> and a
>   compund drawable

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/frag1_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/frag1_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702094/this-tag-and-its-children-can-be-replaced-by-one-textview-and-a-compound-draw)
Combine the TextView and the ImageView in to a single view,  using TextView's setCompoundDrawable*() methods in code, or using android:drawableLeft,etc in xml.
Add

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
```

to your textview and remove the imageview.
UPDATE:

From [answer given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22702094/this-tag-and-its-children-can-be-replaced-by-one-textview-and-a-compound-draw).
This is just a warning and the app should still compile and run. However, this doesn't mean that you just want to dismiss all warnings.
You could use drawableLeft in your xml. Something like

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/txt1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
  android:text="text1 "
  android:textColor="#fff"
  android:textSize="@dimen/sizeNormal"
  android:drawableLeft="@drawable/tick />
```

Comment: Sorry for my late answer, I've been busy with school. I tried to get it working but I just can't merge the the TextView with the ImageView... I don't have any drawable in those two. I looked on google for a way to do it but didn't found one...

Comment: drawable is needed for the compound view.