# Make an image view look the same in every device

Tags: android, xml

I have an image view and a textView.

When i test it in bigger devices, the image changes his position.

layout xml:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/monedas_pow"
    android:text="300"
    android:textSize="29sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/titlecolor"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/summary_btn"
    android:src="@drawable/coin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="525dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/monedas_pow"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="280dp" />
```

[image: It have to look like this]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag)

Comment: You have to create different folders for different devices containing the devices style, dimensions, etc..

Comment: marginBottom is the problem you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have huge margins on bottom and right. Just remove bottom and right margin and add `android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/monedas_pow"`
And you are missing + in `toRightOf` so add it `android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/monedas_pow"`

Comment: But, how could i make it work on every device, not just in mine.I am a begginer

Comment: Where on the screen are you trying to place these Views ?

Comment: On the top left corner

Comment: Thanks man, i had to resize the picture because it was too big, but it works perfectly.

Comment: marginBottom is the problem in your xml,

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout, in that specify align_centerInParent = true for text_view and use layout_below = "your text view id" to your image_view.
Example:

Try this..hope it will work