# Aligning Text and Icons in a TextView Android

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

i am working on a ui design assignment in android studio. i have been able to get this 
[image: My design]

here is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/topImage"
        android:src="@drawable/shebaartist"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

    <TextView android:text="Event Planning and Decoration, Beads and Jewelry Making, Props and Bridals, Aso-Oke #WeMakePoshDesign"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/about"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:background="#F0E68C"
        android:id="@+id/descText" />

    <TextView android:text="150 Alimi Rd, Alore, Ilorin, Kwara State"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/marker"
        android:layout_below="@+id/descText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:id="@+id/addrText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:text="shebaeventss@gmail.com"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/message"
        android:layout_below="@+id/addrText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#F0E68C"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:id="@+id/emailText"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView android:text="07055393673"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:id="@+id/mobilenoText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/emailText"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to align the icons and text in the text views on the same line and with the same size. my question is that how do i do this? please point out my errors and help me with fixing this.

Comment: DO you want text and icons to be vertically center aligned?

Comment: Try removing the single line attribute from the text views!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is what you want, then you just need change gravity from 
**`android:gravity="center"`** to **`android:gravity="center_vertical"`**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Please add gravity property to your TextView with `center` alignment and
>   icon size change with `24dp`.

```
<TextView android:text="Event Planning and Decoration, Beads and Jewelry Making, Props and Bridals, Aso-Oke #WeMakePoshDesign"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/about"
        android:layout_below="@+id/topImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:background="#F0E68C"
        android:id="@+id/descText" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to use a compound drawable, see this answer:

[How do I use a compound drawable instead of a LinearLayout that contains an ImageView and a TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318765/how-do-i-use-a-compound-drawable-instead-of-a-linearlayout-that-contains-an-imag)