# Create a radial gradient programmatically

Tags: java, android

Im trying to reproduce the following gradient programmatically.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient 
        android:startColor="@color/startcolor" 
        android:centerColor="#343434"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:type="radial"
        android:gradientRadius="140"
        android:centerY="45%"
     />
    <corners android:radius="0dp" />
</shape>
```

How can I set programmatically the paramether? Thanks

```
        android:centerY="45%"
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html

To set that specific parameter (I'm assuming a centerX value as you haven't specified one):

```
yourGradientDrawable.setGradientCenter(1.0f,  0.45f);
```

So to create the above gradient (except with different colors) programatically:

```
GradientDrawable g = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TL_BR, new int[] { getResources().getColor(R.color.startcolor), Color.rgb(255, 0, 0), Color.BLUE });
g.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
g.setGradientRadius(140.0f);
g.setGradientCenter(0.0f, 0.45f);
```

Note: The orientation is ignored for a radial gradient but is needed for the constructor that takes colors.

Comment: This does not work for me, there is no radial gradiant jsut a plain white background.

Comment: There's no need to call ```setGradientCenter``` if you want to use default center value