# setCornerRadius not working on Android 4.2.2

Tags: android, drawable, cornerradius

I have implemented pinch to zoom on a ViewGroup whose child Views have background drawables. Upon onScaleEnd, I redraw child Views at the new scale so they're more crisp. However, after re-drawing at smaller scales the rounded corners radii are too big, giving the rectangle shape the wrong appearance. I have code that works for changing the corner radius for all the shapes that works fine on my Kindle Fire HD (based on 4.0.3), but does nothing on my Galaxy Nexus (4.2.2) phone.

Note: I do NOT mutate the drawable because I do want all the drawables based on that resource to change their appearance when I do this.

I've looked at: [change corner radius of drawable programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447835/change-corner-radius-of-drawable-programmatically)
and several other posts, but nothing even hints at different behaviors across devices.

Here's the code:

```
    final LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) context.getResources().getDrawable(drawableId);
    final Drawable drawable = layerDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(drawableLayerId);
    if (drawable instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        final float newRadius = nodeScale > SMALL_TREE_NODE_LAYOUT_THRESHOLD ? normalRadius : smallRadius;

        // this doesn't work
        ((GradientDrawable) drawable).setCornerRadius(newRadius);

        // this doesn't work either
        ((GradientDrawable) drawable).setCornerRadii(new float[] {newRadius, newRadius, newRadius, newRadius, newRadius, newRadius, newRadius, newRadius });
    }
```

Is this a bug in 4.2.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around this, I finally just wrote the code to re-create the Drawables when I need them. This was needed anyway to change all the corner radii, shrink/grow number of shadow rects, etc.