# Overlay over an ImageView on Android

Tags: android, imageview, overlay

So I have a list of images that come from the web, I don't know which color are they and I want to place a text over the ImageView.

My idea is to place the ImageView, an image overlay with transparency gradient over that ImageView and the text above it. I want to mimic this behaviour:

[image]

Is there anyway to do this via XML?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you write the XML for your list items which get inflated in the `getView(...)` of whatever `ListAdapter` you've written you can surely do this.

Something like this for the list item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="#ACACAC"/>

  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Here is your text"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

  </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then you create that drawable/gradient. For that you can recycle the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929877/how-to-make-gradient-background-in-android).

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to **adityajones** I managed to get there :)
So although this is *my* right answer, I'll mark his as the correct one!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/image" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_image" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:shadowColor="#000"
        android:shadowRadius="7.0"
        android:text="This is some random text"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="22sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use a FrameLayout or RelativeLayout. The first View you add to either should be the background ImageView, then obviously you'll need some TextViews and Other ImageViews [or Buttons, or ImageButtons, etc]

Seems like a reasonable layout: a background image, and then one additional view in each corner.

For the gradient, you'll probably want a separate Layout/View at the bottom with a gradient drawable as the background, although I can imagine you might be able to get away with setting the background of one of your TextViews as the gradient.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use a gradient drawable file or set it in your xml..
you can do this pragmatically using `GradientDrawable` Class as explained in this related Question ([Create a radial gradient programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481322/create-a-radial-gradient-programmatically)) then set it as a background for a layout that covers your ImageView, this gives you ability to use different colors and orientations