# How to create a view like this

Tags: android, image, android-recyclerview, picasso

I'm new in android design.
I want to create a view like this:

[image]

In fact, I want to create two things:

1. A header like this image header that has an image with a transparent overlay.
2. Like my header, I want to create recyclerview items, with image and transparent overlay too.

It is necessary to mention that, I want to use Picasso library to show my images.

How to I create this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What your exact problem? With overlays or with organising items for recycler view?

Comment: use recycler view with gridlayout manager

Comment: My problem is that image with overlay transparency.

Comment: can you edit your question and add an image showing what you want to achieve(the Header)? The layout that you have shown above can be easily achieved by using a RelativeLayout or a LinearLayout with LinearLayouts as children.

Comment: Refer to post [Overlay over image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20804564/overlay-over-an-imageview-on-android), hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For grid element you can use RelativeLayout. On the first layer put ImageView with your image, above this you can put View with overlay background (for example semi-transparent black color), and then you can add your text. If you want to create text like on your image (two TextViews above center) you can put empty View element with some height (this height will be like margin between two TextViews) and in top text add layoutAbove="centerViewId" and in bottom text: layoutBelow="centerViewId". I can paste xml code if you want, but I think in this way will teach you more.